# how to get html content of a div element using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a dynamically created html table so I need to get some of the cell values in to jquery variables I tried next() nextAll() cosesst() but nothing work for me.

this is my table created using php

```
if ($result = $hongcon->query($query)) {
                                while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td><div style=\"padding-top: 10px;\"><a class=\"delete\" onclick=\"delete_product($row->id)\">Delete</a></div></td>";
                                    echo "<td><div id=\"id\" style=\"padding: 10px; \">$row->id</div></td>";
                                    echo "<td><div style=\"padding: 10px;\" class=\"edite\">$row->itemName</div></td>";
                                    echo "<td><div id=\"iid\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->iId</div></td>";
                                    echo "<td><div id=\"pid\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->pId</div></td>";
                                    echo "<td><div id=\"image\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->itemImage</div></td>";
                                    echo "<td><div id=\"desc\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->itemDescription</div></td>";
                                    echo "<td><div id=\"pdfone\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->pdfOne</div></td>";
                                    echo "<td><div id=\"pdftwo\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->pdfTwo</div></td>";
                                    echo "<td><div id=\"pdfthree\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->pdfThree</div></td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                };
```

and I have following jquery function in my head section. this code is for testing. always it gives me undefined.

iid, pid, desc are the id that I want to get the values to variables.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("div.edite").on("dblclick", function() {
                    OriginalText = $(this).html();
                    $id = $(this).next("td div").find("#iid").html();
                    alert($id);
      });
            });
```

Comment: You can't have an id multiple times, an id is unique. What you would need are classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bad mistake in your code:
You assign an ID for each row in the table. So your IDs are NOT unique but they should.

So try to make a difference: Use css-classes instead of IDs. Possible:

```
 <table><!-- ... --> <tr>
     <td class="mytable-td mytable-col-iid">...</td>
     <td class="mytable-td mytable-col-pid">...</td>
     <!-- ... -->
 <tr></table>
```

That design has two advantages:

1. You can "hide" your padding in the class `mytable-td`
2. You can get the values via jQuery by calling `$('mytable tr').get(rowIndex).find('.mytable-col-iid').html()`

Comment: what is the rowIndex ?

Comment: @Yasitha Normally you have several rows in a table. So the row index is the number of the row (count beginning with 0) you would like to check. So `rowIndex` is of type `number`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you correctly. do you mean to add a counter to while loop?

Comment: @Yasitha Try `$('div.edite').onclick(function(){ $(this).closest('tr').find('.mytable-col-iid').html(); });`

That works in your case

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
$id = $(this).next("td div").find("#iid").html();
```

But that won't work because there is no `td` that is next from the `div.edite`. And also, you won't be able to find the `div#iid` inside the next `td div` because it *is* that `div` already. Finally, you should avoid using IDs in this code because you will end up with duplicates which won't work. Change the above line to this and it should work:

```
$id = $(this).closest("TR").next("td div").html();
```

Answer (score 1):

ids should be unique within the entire document.
I think you should change the code a bit adding a suffix to each id (p.j. the number of the row)
Anyway, you could select those values with a something like
 `$(this).parent().parent().find("#iid").html();`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
$id = $(this).next("td div").find("#iid").html();
```

Use like this

```
$id = $(this).parent().siblings().find("#iid").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your php code in order to generate table rows with unique numeric identifier

```
<?php
if ($result = $hongcon->query($query)) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><div style=\"padding-top: 10px;\"><a class=\"delete\" onclick=\"delete_product($row->id)\">Delete</a></div></td>";
    echo "<td><div id=\"id_$row->id\" style=\"padding: 10px; \">$row->id</div></td>";
    echo "<td><div style=\"padding: 10px;\" class=\"edite\" editId=\"$row->id\">$row->itemName</div></td>";
    echo "<td><div id=\"iid_$row->id\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->iId</div></td>";
    echo "<td><div id=\"pid_$row->id\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->pId</div></td>";
    echo "<td><div id=\"image_$row->id\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->itemImage</div></td>";
    echo "<td><div id=\"desc_$row->id\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->itemDescription</div></td>";
    echo "<td><div id=\"pdfone_$row->id\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->pdfOne</div></td>";
    echo "<td><div id=\"pdftwo_$row->id\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->pdfTwo</div></td>";
    echo "<td><div id=\"pdfthree_$row->id\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">$row->pdfThree</div></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
};
?>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $("div.edite").on("dblclick",function() {
                $iid = "iid_"+$(this).attr('editId');
                OriginalText = $(this).html();
                $id = $("#"+$iid).html();
                alert($id);
            });
});
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to enumerate IDs

Comment: I think you're right, and yes i saw your answer and i think it's definitely more efficient than mine.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this instead:**

```
$id = $(this).parent("td div").find("#iid").html();
```

**Because in your current code you have:**

```
$id = $(this).next("td div").find("#iid").html();
```

And that wouldn't work because there is no `td` next to the `div`. Due to that, you won't be able to find `div#iid` inside the next `td div`.